# Prevent Network Manager from using modified dhclient.conf file in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, network-manager, dhclient

I use Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. Dhclient conf file is at `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` . Everytime I connect to wifi (saved or new hotspot), Network Manager (NM) creates a conf file at `/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlan0.conf` and deletes it when it's disconnected. This file contains contents of `dhclient.conf` plus entries added by NM. How do I stop NM from adding these entries? It adds 9 lines, excluding newline. I do not want any of these lines.

Answer (score 0):

NM searches for multiple files to merge: https://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/src/dhcp/nm-dhcp-dhclient.c?id=eb77d4ed28fb7d72020fc4bce2a7f3477f0b8c1d#n219

If you turn on debug-logging, NM will also log lines like:

```
NetworkManager[388]: <debug> [1481627729.0469] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): creating composite dhclient config /var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-wlp3s0.conf
NetworkManager[388]: <debug> [1481627729.0469] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): looking for existing config /etc/NetworkManager/dhclient-7111201a-568f-4568-a0ed-cd1d4df11e8f.conf 
...
```

To avoid loading your dhclient.conf, create an empty File that shaddows it (i didn't actually test this)

Comment: hi, thank you. I looked through that link but couldn,t figure out how to solve my problem. I like NM to use entries in the dhclient.conf file. But do not want NM to add its own entries. These are the entries that NM adds:

Comment: `send host-name "ja9-stash"; # added by NetworkManager

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
option ms-classless-static-routes code 249 = array of unsigned integer 8;
option wpad code 252 = string;

also request rfc3442-classless-static-routes;
also request ms-classless-static-routes;
also request static-routes;
also request wpad;
also request ntp-servers;`

Answer (score 0):

A possible fix is to create the file /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf with the content:

```
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
```

This will disable the use of the internal dhcp client that uses the generated merged file.

Note: You will need dhclient to be installed.

Comment: Would be nice if it says from where and how to install this needed bit.